# T-sql database assignment from DataCamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just started learning T-SQL, can anyone point where im wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

**The Problem:**

The `AdventureWorksLT` database includes a table-valued function named `dbo.ufnGetAllCategories`, which returns a table of product categories (e.g. 'Road Bikes') and parent categories (for example 'Bikes').

**Instructions:**

Write a query that uses this function to return a list of all products including their parent category and their own category. Make sure to use the aliases provided, and default column names elsewhere.

**what i have tried :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetAllCategories(@ProductCategoryID AS Integer);
RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN
(SELECT C.ParentProductCategoryName AS ParentCategory,
   C.ProductCategoryName AS Category,
   P.ProductID, P.Name AS ProductName
FROM SalesLT.Product AS P JOIN SalesLT.ProductCategory AS C 
ON P.ProductCategoryID = C.ProductCategoryID 
JOIN dbo.ufnGetAllCategories() AS f
ON P.ProductCategoryID = f.ProductCategoryID
ORDER BY ParentCategory, Category, ProductName);
```

**My output:**

Incorrect submission

Column ParentCategory in the solution does not have a column with the same name and values in your results.

Comment: can you please edit your post to provide some sample data from each of the tables so we can see the Schema more clearly.  Why are you creating the function at the top?  Aren't you just supposed to be using the provided function in order to solve the problem, not designing the function?  Your output at the bottom doesn't really tell us anything because it's not a SQL error, that's just something on whatever homework site you're submitting this to lol.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Thanks TheGameiswar.
Here is the uncorrected problem
    SELECT C.ParentProductCategoryName AS ___,
           C.ProductCategoryName AS ___,
           P.ProductID, P.Name AS ___
    FROM SalesLT.Product AS P
    JOIN dbo.___() AS ___
    ON P.___ = C.___
    ORDER BY ParentCategory, Category, ProductName;

The tables are below

Comment: Table1 : ProductModelProductDescription (Column headings are below)


ProductModelID  ProductDescriptionID  Culture rowguid   ModifiedDate

Comment: Table 2: ProductCategory (Column headings are next) >


ProductCategoryID ParentProductCategoryID Name rowguid  ModifiedDate

Comment: Table 3: ProductDescription (Column headings are next) >


ProductDescriptionID Description rowguid ModifiedDate

Comment: Table 4: Product (Column headings are next) > 

ProductID Name ProductNumber Color StandardCost ListPrice Size Weight ProductCategoryID ProductModelID SellStartDate SellEndDate DiscontinuedDate ThumbNailPhoto ThumbnailPhotoFileName rowguid ModifiedDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you were very close in solving this challenge. The function is a table valued function.

```
select *
from [dbo].[ufnGetAllCategories]()
```

And gives the output as shown below.

[image: Result from table valued function]

So you can use dbo.ufnGetAllCategories() as an ordinary table.

```
select C.ParentProductCategoryName as ParentCategory
     , C.ProductCategoryName as Category
     , P.ProductID
     , P.Name as ProductName
from SalesLT.Product as P
     join dbo.ufnGetAllCategories() as C on P.ProductCategoryID = C.ProductCategoryID 
     order by ParentCategory, Category, ProductName;
```

Resulting in:

[image: Overall result]

Comment: Thanks Koen Ubbink, Using your code word for word give a result exactly as the one you posted with some caveats. First, i got a code error; "Incorrect submission: Column ParentCategory in the solution does not have a column with the same name and values in your results". Second, the aliases were not used to replace the column header names and I don't know why.
Last Question: Why did you used two asterisks (*) before and after the letter f in the SELECT statement?
Thank you for your help

Comment: The double * were meant to make the text bold, it is just text formatting. But I think it does not work in code format.

Comment: Can you provide the course that you are taking? I can not find the specific course that addresses t-sql, only [DataCamp - Introduction to Databases in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-relational-databases-in-python)

Comment: I am actually taking the course on EdX platform thought by Graeme Malcolm of Microsoft but the exercises are done on DataCamp platform through a partnership. The course on EdX platform "Querying with Transact-SQL" url is https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DAT201x+2T2017/info. I wonder if you will be able to use the url since it's connected to my personal dashboard. Here is the url for the exercise on the DataCamp https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/querying-with-transact-sql/lab-7-using-table-expressions?ex=3.
Thanks

Comment: I took this course a while back, however with out the DataCamp platform for the exercises. It seems much beter right now.

You can drop the join with the ProductCategory as it is already joined by the function. I have updated my previous answer.